# Class not found in autoload.php on line 14 on some docker hosts

Tags: php, docker, nginx, laravel-5

I try to create dockerfile for laravel 5.5 application and nginx. I use similar to following dockerfile:

```bash
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.3.7

# we cannot directly work in /var/www/html beaouse in richarvey/nginx-php-fpm is VOLUME directive so if we create
# files in this directory - they will 'disappear' - so we use /tmp dir. 
WORKDIR /tmp/project

# due to docker cache
COPY ./composer.json .
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader

ADD . .
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize
RUN php artisan key:generate

ADD ./config/server-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD if [ -f index.php ]; then \
        rm index.php &&\            
        mv /tmp/project/* /var/www/html/ && \
        mv /tmp/project/.* /var/www/html/ | : &&\
        php artisan config:clear &&\
        php artisan cache:clear ; \
    fi &&\
    echo "Try connect to db and set up schema..." && \
    php artisan migrate --seed --force &&\
    /start.sh
```

My project/config/server-nginx.conf looks like that:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6


    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    # Add stdout logging
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    access_log /dev/stdout;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params; 

        ...            
    }

}
```

The problem is that everything works fine in my macOs and ubuntu, however my client which use Docker Claud and DigitalOcean have following problem after container run (so building step is fine, but after container run it is killed by docker - so in CMD dockerfile part):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/artisan(18): require()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem sometimes (! - on some hosts - why?) appear when we use `composer ...` in some directory (with php project) and then we move/rename that directory (by `mv ...` bash command in CMD dockerfile part) - so if we do it (in some hosts) then file autoload.php (generated by composer) [will have not proper paths to php classes](https://github.com/acquia/lightning-project/issues/26).

However in this case we use dir `tmp/project` (and call `composer` inside) and then move it to /var/www/html, because we cannot directly work in /var/www/html because in `richarvey/nginx-php-fpm` is VOLUME directive so if we create files in this directory - they will 'disappear' - so we use /tmp dir.

Additional there is also problem when we want to link by `ln` `/var/www/html` to `/tmp/project` and use `chown -R nginx:nginx /tmp/project` because it will go into infinit loop and never ends... :( (why?).

## SOLUTION

Is to change root dir in `project/config/server-nginx.conf` to:

```
root /var/www/app/public;
```

Then change workdir in dockerfile to:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/app
```

And in dockerfile CMD section add

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/app/storage
```

To give write access to laravel only to storage directory (in which laravel save work data) (if we use `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/app/storage` it will newer 'ends' (go into infinit loop) :( )

In this way we avoid move `composer` compiled directory and everything works grate on all hosts :)